# Can I get my scammed ETH back?

Tags: dapps, scam

In a Coin Membership room, the leader introduced the ICO token project and said that now is the seed sale period.
He showed me a screenshot of the site and told me to deposit Ethereum, talking about a DAO wallet based on the Ethereum chain.

So, at first, I sent 4 and 1.5 total 5.5 ETH to that address, but the promised Ethereum did not arrive on the payment date. They said that 10 ether should be exceeded, so I sent 3,2 total 5ETH to that address and list up them based on 10.5 ether, but it was not paid on the promised date either.

Later, he said because I sent ethereum below gwei40, the smart contract did not work, so I had to send the same number of ethereum again to gwei60. So I sent another 2, 3, 3.5, 2 in all 10.5 ether.
I was tricked by a scammer and sent 21 ether to the scam address.

However, I eventually found out that I had been scammed.
I found out the official homepage of the coin through Googling and showed the screenshot to the administrator. The administrator said it was a scam, and the address I sent the Ethereum to was also a scam address.

Another admin told me he can help me. He sent me a link and said it was a recovery program. He says that if I deposit 6.1ETH into my wallet and use the recovery program, I can get 21 ethers back.
He says "*an amount of Ether txid is needed to merge and retraced your 21ETH back into your wallet*"

Comment: [I added a generic question and answer: I got scammed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-on-ethereum-what-to-do/152374#152374).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS A SCAM.

The ETH you deposited cannot be recovered unless the scammer sends it back.

Take the loss and use it as a learning experience for the future.